# regex set =self in comma seperated string

Tags: regex

I am using Notepad++ and have this kind of string:
`a,b,c,d,e` and want to make it `a=a,b=b,c=c,d=d,e=e,`

I tried replacing `((^,)*),` with `\1=\1,` but it just appends the = without the second "copy". What am I missing? Does it have to do with parentheses nesting? Using /2 instead of /1 does the same.

Comment: Try `([^,]*)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

**Find What**: `([^,]+),?`
**Replace With**: `$1=$1,`

Here, `([^,]+),?` matches and captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than a comma and then an optional comma, and replaces with the contents of Group 1, `=`, Group 1 value again and a comma.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RPlYOG/1) and a demo screenshot below:

[image]